# Make a list of US Birth : how to make a string to int in list

Tags: python, valueerror

```
def read_csv(filename):
    string_data = open(filename).read()
    string_list = string_data.split("\n")[1:]
    final_list = []

    for row in string_list:
        string_fields = row.split(",")
        int_fields = []
        for value in string_fields:
            int_fields.append(value)
        final_list.append(int_fields)
    return final_list

cdc_list = read_csv("US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv")
cdc_list[0:3]
```

when I run this code, I got result just like this:

```
[['1994', '1', '1', '6', '8096'], ['1994', '1', '2', '7', '7772'], ['1994', '1', '3', '1', '10142']]
```

But I want the result something like this:

```
[[1994, 1, 1, 6, 8096], [1994, 1, 2, 7, 7772], [1994, 1, 3, 1, 10142]]
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: If you are getting an exception, you should post the full exception, it helps people to help you. If this is `csv` data use the `csv` module, it would make it much easier to read. Did you try printing `value`?

Comment: `[1994,1,1,6,8097]` isn't able to be converted to a float

Comment: What about converting the `str` to `int` via `int_fields.append(int(value))`?

Comment: @Ella, it is very hard to answer your question when you keep changing it. You now seem to be parsing things correctly (though `csv` module would make much of your code redundant).

Comment: @AChampion, sorry about it. I'm new to here.. I tried value and it helped

Comment: @a_guestm I tried it but I've got ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 1):

The following list comprehension will convert the strings in the sublists of `cdc_list` to integers:

```
[list(map(int, s)) for s in cdc_list]
```